# Why in C++ append <eax> after a variable

Tags: c++

Eax and edx [...] are CPU registers, so far so good; but why append a variable with the name of a certain register `<xxx>`. It seems that the variable is to associate with the register or perhaps store in it? I infer that, or maybe it's just a type???

```
int __usercall sub_403DF0<eax>(int result<eax>, int a2<edx>)
{
int v2; // ebx@1
int v3; // esi@1

v2 = result;
v3 = a2;
```

Comment: What compiler and platform do you use?

Comment: This is not c++, it's hex rays pseudo-c. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes what are we talking about. Some compilers will optimize function calls by passing parameters in registers instead of on the stack.

Comment: It's specifying a register calling convention, where the first parameter is in the `eax` register, and the second parameter is in the `edx` register and the return code is in the `eax` register

Answer (score 1):

That is for certain not C++. You will have to ask whoever designed this specific variant.